# How dynamically to put values in a column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, indexof

I'm trying to put the name of certain sheets in a column (excluding the names of other sheets I don't want). I have created the array but, it does not appear. I want the information to be placed in `A3:A105`.

I have tried to set the value of the column using `indexOf`.

```
function sheetNames() {
  var out = [];
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var exclude = ["About Me", "Contractors", "All Group Bids", "Bid Summary"];

  var bidsheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Bid Summary");
  var column = bidsheet.getRange(3, 1, 105).getValue(); 

  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (exclude.indexOf(sheets[i].getName()) === -1) 
      {column.setValue(out.push(sheets[i].getName()))};

    return out; 
    }
  }


//Nothing appears in the column.
```

[ENTER IMAGE DESCRIPTION HERE!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJzmS.png)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51508336/1595451

Comment: Thanks but, I still couldn't get it to work for me. I'm extremely new to coding. I tried to determine what I needed from that. I still get only one sheet name repeating all the way down. I created a new function referencing the old one. see a pic above.

Answer (score 1):

At a glance, I think `var column = bidsheet.getRange(3, 1, 105).getValue();` could be the problem.

Try taking out the `getValue()` part, so `column` is a [`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) object. Then you can call [`setValue`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) or perhaps [`setValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) on that range a little later on.

*Note:*

- [`SetValue`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) takes a single value, and should be used on a range made up of a single cell. Eg:

  ```
  var cell = sheet.getRange("B2");
  cell.setValue(100);
  ```
- [`SetValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) takes a two-dimensional array of values, and should set used on a multi-cell array. Eg:

  ```
  var values = [
    [ "2.000", "1,000,000", "$2.99" ]
  ];

  var range = sheet.getRange("B2:D2");
  range.setValues(values);
  ```

Rather than calling `setValue` each time you iterate through that loop, a better approach may be to use that loop to build up an array of sheet names and then make a single call to `setValues` to write that data to your selected range.